# Google Script - Add Checkbox to Inputs in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I make my student quizzes using HTML and Google Script. In my index.html file, I have different inputs with id’s that are labeled as q1 for question 1, q2 for question two, so on and so forth. Using an add record function, I compare those inputs to those at the top row of the Google Sheet file which has the answers.

I am wanting to put a checkmark next to the id tag of each input they got wrong on the index.html file. Is there a way to go from the Google Script file back to the index file and put check mark next to the questions that are incorrect based off the == comparison to the answer key at the top row of the Google Sheet file? I’m not sure where I would start to do something like this which makes an object appear next to an input this way, and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I thought that in your question, when you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image and also provide your current script and explain the current issue of your script, it will help users think of the solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.